# Not able to upgrade my ipod touch to ios 5.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i  upgraded my xcode to 5.0 today morning and when i tried to run the application on device. i wasnt able to run since its 4.2.1.when i tried to upgrade my ipod touch using itunes.i m getting this "This version of the iPod software (4.2.1) is the current version."could you help me how to upgrade this device

Comment: Not really a programming question, is it?

Comment: yup this is not a programming question..but i  m in a dire need to update  my product to ma client usin io5

Comment: yup u r rite its xcode 4.2 .i ve got one device that's my ipod touch and its of second generation..

Comment: @kingston That still doesn't justify asking off-topic questions.

Comment: dude if u really wanna down vote just go ahead..why argue?i m in a dire need to crack this thing up.i m facing my own nightmares right now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this method if your device is a second or first generation : http://cydiahelp.com/whited00r-5.1-install-ios-5-on-iphone-3g-2g-ipod-touch-2g-1g/

Comment: Whited00r is based on iOS 3.1.3, so he won't be able to run the application on the device anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If your iPod Touch is 1st or 2nd generation then iOS 5 is not compatible with it - see the bottom of [this page](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html). Similarly, my old iPhone 3G is unable to go higher than iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Which generation is your ipod touch? It sounds like you have a 2nd generation ipod touch. This means you can't install iOS 5 on it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to update you iPod touch, depending on the model.
However, you should be able to change the OS deployment target in xcode, so that it will still run on an OS lower than 5.0.

Comment: Doesn't help with testing on an actual device.

Comment: It would if the target has been set to 5.0, it won't run on anything lower.

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to test on a device running iOS5.

Comment: Of course you can, also his problem is that the device is not iOS 5, but he's installed the iOS 5 SDK

Comment: But his device isn't running iOS5. So he can't test it on his device while it is running iOS5. Which is the reason he is asking the question.